# Unable to install mysql-server-5.6

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

My website was running fine on server version 5.5, but now it hangs on the installation of version 5.6.

I've tried removing it, purging it, even removing the `/etc/mysql` folder, then reinstalling it but alas it has not been successful.

Either it hangs saying that `init.d couldn't start mysql`, or it complains about me setting the root password.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's some output:

```
maxwells@mellifluous:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...



Job for mysql.service failed. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up php5-mysql (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2) ...
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for cli SAPI

Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/mysqli.ini with new version
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for cli SAPI

Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini with new version
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for cli SAPI
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php5 (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
```

EDIT: I eventually just removed everything and backed up from my backup files!

Comment: Can you provide some output from your attempts to install or start?

Comment: I edited the original question with some output.